# "localhost didn't send data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" and "curl: (52) Empty reply from server"

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, dockerfile

I am getting empty data with below mentioned error when I try to access outside of Docker container. I don't have any issue with both curl and wget commands inside the Docker container. The container is based on Angular JS image.

"localhost didn't send data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"  and "curl: (52) Empty reply from  server"

Please help.

Sorry! Forgot to post actual code. Here my Dockerfile and package.json files.

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "angularjs-project”,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -H 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "primeng": "^4.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
    FROM node:6
RUN mkdir -p /angularjs-sample
ADD . /angularjs-sample
WORKDIR /angularjs-sample
RUN cd /angularjs-sample

RUN npm cache clean
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install
RUN npm update
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["ng", "serve"]
```

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2522

Comment: @VijayKrishna, I wish that the link you provided would solve the problem. I have been through the link so many times today to understand the problem. Could you tell me which file or location of Angular JS I need to update with 0.0.0.0 in order to resolve this problem? By the way, Please forgive me if this question is silly because I am new to Angular JS and Docker.

Comment: Please post your dockerfile and package.json too

Comment: Please paste steps in detail you are doing with the dockerfile.

Comment: If the process inside the container is only listening to "localhost", it will only be accessible from inside the container. Make sure the process is listening on "any" address (i.e. listening on `0.0.0.0`) so that it accepts connections from outside the container. https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2522#issuecomment-94878176

Comment: Having said the above; make sure to post the exact steps you're following, and all relevant information; the current information in your question does not show any code for others to look at, so all answers will be a "wild guess"

Comment: Hello @all, Thank you so much for your response. I have posted my actual code of Dockerfile and package.json files. Please help. Thanks again.

Comment: What reply were you expecting from the server? I don't know much node, but I don't see anything in the code above that would respond with content.

Comment: @BMitch, I was expecting home page of my angular js project as I was getting when I curl inside the docker container. I don't understand why I was getting information when I was inside docker container but empty page when curl from outside the container.

Comment: Hello All, I was able to get the contents of the project after adding ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 at the end of the docker run command. I am not sure if this might be helpful to others but I put here just in case so someone may not need to go through as I did.

Comment: Ideal way to do this is to bind the host machine ip address to your container when creating. You should not initiate running of your application from docker file. 
Create container, bind with your host machine and the write a script to boot your application.

Comment: Hello @Sohan, Thanks for your response. You're right. I did not use the same code as I mentioned in my Dockerfile as above. I deleted RUN ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port 4200 line from the code and used CMD ["ng", "serve"] instead . After that I added ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 at the tail of Docker run command. The actual command looks like this: docker run -d -p 4200:4200 --name "container-name" image-name ng serve --host 0.0.0.0. I hope this helps someone like me.

Comment: Put as an answer, so can see it :)

Comment: docker run -d -p 4200:4200 --name "container-name" image-name ng serve --host 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideal way to do this I would suggest is to bind the host machine ip address to your container when creating. You should not initiate running of your application from docker file. Create container, bind with your host machine and the write a script to boot your application

You can do this as ,

```
docker run -d -p 4545:8553--name my-container my-image my-command
```

Where "**8553**" can be your application default internal port binned with "**4545**" external port

Comment: Can i get reason for down vote for this accepted answer?

Answer (score 10):

```
CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

When an HTTP client like a web browser (or in this case, curl) sends an HTTP request, the server needs the client’s IP address, so it knows where to send the response.  When you run a local development server, it inspects that IP address, and won’t even respond to requests that aren’t coming from 127.0.0.1 (localhost).  That keeps other folks on your network (say, sitting in the same Starbucks) from using the dev server as a way to hack your box.

When you run a dev server in a guest container or VM, and run the client (curl) on the host machine, the server sees a different IP address, and refuses to respond.  Most servers let you specify a mask of what IP addresses are valid clients.  0.0.0.0 means fugetaboutit, accept all client IPs.  It gives the bouncer the night off.

Comment: @Rob What am I missing?  It's not obvious to me what I should have done differently.

Comment: Don't just blurt out code. Explain what you are doing. How does it answer the question? What does it do that solves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
FROM node:latest as builder

EXPOSE 4200

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@16.1.0

RUN npm ci --force

COPY . .

RUN npm run build:production

CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

1. For creating image => `docker build -t myimage .`
2. For running image => `docker run -p 32544:4200 myimage`

Be carefull, if you face the same error again, change the 4200 to another random port!
Also '32544' is just random port as well, you can set whatever you want!

```
docker run host-port:docker-port yourImageName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if the **--host** parameter is deprecated for your version

```
 const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log(
      ` Application is running on: http://localhost:${port} env: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
    );
  });
```